# Connecting Xero to Salesforce

Tags: apex, integration

Good day everyone, I am trying to connect to Xero using Salesforce Apex. I've found this link: https://github.com/benedwards44/Apex-for-Xero/ and I find it very useful. I can now sync my salesforce data to Xero. The thing I want to do at the moment is that, I want to sync my Xero data to salesforce. So if there is a new data in Xero, it will be sync to salesforce.What is the best way to do it ? Is it advisable to use outbound message ? Or what is the best way to do it ? Please help. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I would think using External Objects to directly fetch Xero data via its [Accounting API](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/api-overview/) is a quick start.

Comment: Do you mean I have to create something like a batch process to query those data i need in Xero and put it in salesforce ?

Comment: No, I mean to create external objects in SF to directly fetch the data from Xero on demand. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_external_objects.htm